# Custom image toolbar WTL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wtl

I want to create a toolbar with custom image buttons, I have the images in .ico format how can I add them to the toolar in WTL? I'm trying to edit the images in the toolbar list, but there such poor quality, how can I add better quality images?

Comment: It looks like there are two questions here, how to change the images used in a WTL toolbar and how to edit the images themselves. You might want to clarify. The answer to the first question lies in understaing CImageList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a WTL Toolbar control that is already created you can attach images to it with the `SetImageList()` and `SetHotImageList()` methods of the `CToolBarCtrl` class. E.g.

```
CToolBarCtrl toolbar;
CImage image;
CBitmap bitmap;

// ... load the image into the bitmap ...

images.Create(32, 32, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 0, 1);

// repeat this for each image you want to use in the toolabr
images.Add(bitmap, RGB(255, 255, 255));

toolbar.SetImageList(images.Detach());

//... do the same for the hot (hover) images ...
```

The images can then be used by referencing the return value of the `CImageList:Add()` method.

**Make sure** you detach the image list from the `CImageList` class as I have done here otherwise the image list will be deleted when it goes out of scope.

Comment: the internet is really short on wtl examples, any rich learning resources?

Comment: Yeah, I have found it really difficult to find any good examples. Your best bet is to look at http://www.viksoe.dk/code/wtldoc.htm, The 'WTL Developers guide, and the WTL Source code itself. Gamedev has a couple of articles that provide a good introduction (http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/using-the-windows-template-library-part-1-gett-r2042) and for everything else there's Google and SO... :-)